# Problem comparing between variable in unix

Tags: bash, sh

I have a problem where i compare the first line of the file to a paremeter i send, how can i fix it?

```
./lab12.sh lyrics "Yesterday"
```

```
if [[ "$1" == "lyrics" ]]
then
for file in /tmp/beatles/*.txt ; do
          if [[ head -1 $file == "$2" ]] //problem here !
          then
          echo cat | tail +3 $file
          fi
          done 
          fi
echo "Error - Song name not found"
fi
```

Comment: Post your code into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: @JRFerguson the problem is where i suspected it is, problem is idk how to fix it.

Comment: At your problem line you need: `if [[ $(head -1 "$file" == "$2") ]]`. This is [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution)

Comment: @JRFerguson `$(head -1 "$file) == "$2"`

Comment: @chepner Oops, but of course. Thanks.

Comment: @chepner $(head -1 "$file") == "$2"  ***. It works now, thanks to you all.

Comment: `IFS= read -r line < "$file"; if [[ $line == "$2" ]]` would be even better: no external process needed.

Comment: I'm not sure what `echo cat | tail +3 $file` is supposed to do.

Comment: @chepner print lines starting from the 3rd line, is there a better way?

Comment: `tail +3 "$file"`. The pipe serves no purpose.

Comment: @chepner it lets me print from the 3rd line...

Comment: If you give `tail` a file argument, it ignores its standard input anyway, which is why the pipe isn't doing anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the "problem line" you cited, you are looking for [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution), thereby allowing the output of the command to replace the command itself.

Your line should read:

```
if [[ $(head -1 "$file") == "$2" ]]
```